# gitlab-ci cache on kubernetes with minio-service not working anymore

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, minio

I'm running gitlab 10.4.3 with gitlab-runner 10.4.0 as a kubernetes deployment with kubernetes runner and a minio-server for caching. I installed it according to the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/autoscaling.html#install-the-cache-server).

Everything worked with the cache as expected, when adding the appropriate settings to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`-file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - compile-templates.sh
    - yarn install
    - yarn run build
```

The pipeline output did fill the cache the first time and subsequent runs on the same branch correctly pulled and pushed the cache:

```
Running on gitlab/runner-abcdefg-project-123-concurrent-123456 via gitlab-runner-123456-987654...
Cloning repository for feature/gitlab-cache with git depth set to 1...
Cloning into '/group/project'...
Checking out b1348594 as feature/gitlab-cache...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for feature/gitlab-cache...
Downloading cache.zip from http://minio-service:9000/runner/runner/abcdefg/project/123/feature/gitlab-cache 
Successfully extracted cache
$ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
Login Succeeded
[...snip...]
Creating cache feature/gitlab-cache...
node_modules/: found 26281 matching files
Uploading cache.zip to http://minio-service:9000/runner/runner/abcdefg/project/123/feature/gitlab-cache 
Created cache
```

However, after some runs it suddenly stopped working - and I do not know why. I've also tried a job-global cache-definition to no avail - it seems that the gitlab-runner is simply ignoring the setting and just skips the "Checking cache part":

```
Running on gitlab/runner-abcdefg-project-123-concurrent-123456 via gitlab-runner-123456-987654...
Cloning repository for feature/gitlab-cache with git depth set to 1...
Cloning into '/group/project'...
Checking out b1348594 as feature/gitlab-cache...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
Login Succeeded
[...snip...]
Job succeeded
```

My gitlab-runner config.toml has the appropriate settings:

```
[[runners]]
  // ...
  [runners.kubernetes]
  // ...
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    // I've also tried http://minio-service:9000 to no avail
    ServerAddress = "minio-service:9000"
    AccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    SecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    BucketName = "runner"
    Insecure = true
```

*Note:* If I change the settings to invalid ones, I do not get any error messages in the runners logs.

The port is reachable from the runner itself *and* from job pods:

```
$ curl -s "http://minio-service:9000"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied.</Message><Key></Key><BucketName></BucketName><Resource>/</Resource><RequestId>12345</RequestId><HostId>12345</HostId></Error>
```

The bucket on minio exists as checked in the local volume *and* via the minio client `mc`.

There are no errors in the logs of the pods of gitlab-runner or the minio-server.

It's just like the cache-settings of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` are simply ignored and I'm out of ideas on what's left to check. Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was an invalid documentation in combination with a silent ignore of invalid cache:keys. If a branch is e.g. named `feature/some-new-thing`, the resulting key of `"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"` would lead to an invalid cache:key containing a "/"-character - which in turn would render the whole cache-section invalid, but which is silently ignored.

Instead, just use `"${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG}"`, which will contain an url-safe - and therefore cache:key-safe - version of the branch name:

```
cache:
  key: "${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG}"
  paths:
    - node_modules/
```

A [bug report](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3085) has been opened.