# gitlab-ci cache on kubernetes with minio-service not working

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, minio

I'm running gitlab with current gitlab-runner 10.3.0 as a kubernetes deployment with a minio-server for caching. Everything is deployed using helm. The gitlab runner's helm is customized using this `values.yml`:

```
cache:
  cacheType: s3
  s3ServerAddress: http://wizened-tortoise-minio:9000
  s3BucketName: runners
  s3CacheInsecure: false
  cacheShared: true
  secretName: s3access
  # s3CachePath: gitlab_runner
```

The `s3access` is defined as cluster secret, the `runners` bucket exists on minio. Problem is that the cache is not being populated although the build log doesn't show any issues:

```
Checking cache for onekey-6
Successfully extracted cache
...
Creating cache onekey-6...
.m2/repository/: found 5909 matching files         
Created cache
```

Looking into the minio bucket it is empty. I'm confident that the gitlab runner `s3ServerAddress` is correct as changing it shows as errors in the build process (here e.g. when using https):

```
Checking cache for onekey-6...
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Retrying...                               
Failed to extract cache

Creating cache onekey-6...
.m2/repository/: found 5909 matching files         
Uploading cache.zip to https://wizened-tortoise-minio/runners/gitlab_runner/runner/b87d7697/project/1644/onekey-6 
WARNING: Retrying...                               
Uploading cache.zip to https://wizened-tortoise-minio/runners/gitlab_runner/runner/b87d7697/project/1644/onekey-6 
WARNING: Retrying...                               
Failed to create cache
Uploading cache.zip to https://wizened-tortoise-minio/runners/gitlab_runner/runner/b87d7697/project/1644/onekey-6 
FATAL: Put https://wizened-tortoise-minio
```

I've also added `echo $S3_SERVER_ADDRESS` to the build and it's empty.

So: how do I need to configure gitlab-runner to use minio for caching?

Note: I'm aware of [gitlab-ci cache on kubernetes with minio-service not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714415/gitlab-ci-cache-on-kubernetes-with-minio-service-not-working-anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of completeness the problem is with:

```
s3ServerAddress: http://wizened-tortoise-minio:9000
```

While gitlab apparently does some "presence" check where it accepts the `http://` it doesn't when actually cloning the cache. Unfortunately it seems to silently swallow the error. Working version needs:

```
s3ServerAddress: wizened-tortoise-minio:9000
```

Opened gitlab issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3539#note_103371588